# Get reportportal url result after pytest execution

Tags: python, pytest, reportportal

Is there a way to get report portal report link after test execution is done?

I exectue the tests as such:
`pytest --reportportal`

which indeed generates a report on ui level, but nothing in cli or anywhere that i can get it via a script to post it to slack after exec